# Why am I unable to checkout an SVN repo after an upgrade from 1.6 to 1.8?

Tags: svn, upgrade

I just upgraded my svn server from 1.6 to 1.8. Now no one can communicate with the svn server. They are told the repos don't exist.

----- edit -----

I did run into some issue during the upgrade:

- upgrade failed because of a dead repo (http://repo.andrewfarley.com/centos/5/i386/repodata/repomd.xml)
- created new `.repo` based on this: http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-1-8-on-centos-rhel/
- 1.6 was upgraded to 1.8
- had to start Apache and got more errors
- found that "LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so, LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so" were commented out
- uncommented those two lines and Apache started

I can run `svn upgrade` on the server to upgrade the repos but no one can commit, checkout, etc. from their machines.

Comment: Can you provide OS ?

Comment: Sorry, running RedHat (RHEL) 5.

Comment: updated question with more info

Comment: Is modules/mod_dav_svn.so available ?

Comment: it's located at `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so` not sure if that validates if it's "available"

Comment: I've tried kill and starting `svnserve` but that didn't fix the issue

Comment: I assume that the clients are also using svn 1.8, and not 1.6?

Comment: I'm using 1.8 and I'm having the same issue

Comment: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` shows: "LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so"

Comment: I'm getting an "Unable to connect to a repository at URLl..." first